# Being in the US as a European citizen, trying to open an account in Europe

Tags: banking, bank-account, international

I am currently in the US, as a European citizen, but planning to travel to Europe soon. I am looking to open an account in Europe before leaving the US, so I can wire some money before I leave the US to a European account.

HSBC is the only one which could help, but they require some kind of reason for the European account. Seems like they only accept things like, I have a new job there, I have a property there, I married a EU citizen, etc.
France would be the best (my relatives live in Hungary, but there is no HSBC in Hungary), because Global view and Global transfer works with French accounts.

Question:

1. Does anybody know if HSBC international department will accept any other reason, like "I would like to move there".
2. Can I ask my relatives to go to France, rent a property there(in my name), and say that I have an address in France, and I am moving there, because my "family lives there".
3. Or, I have a relative here in the US, who works for DELL, should I provide his US number and ask him to talk to them and tell them about me that "I work for DELL in the US, and now they offered me to transfer my position to DELL in France, and I will accept it, but I need an account in France"
4. Any other idea that the HSBC international department would accept?

Comment: My experience, moving from the UK to Canada, was that HSBC requires you to appear in person to open your account.  Ask HSBC what documents you will require to open an account in France.  You will need a French address.  Once that is done and you have opened your French account, you can use their Global View to link your various accounts and simply "drag and drop" money between accounts.

Comment: From  what I have seen, banks outside the US  are rather quick to turn away US citizens **or** green card holders because the benefit to them is not there compared to the risk of US-imposed penalties.

Comment: Does your US bank have an international presence? You may not need to open an European account if you bank with Wells Fargo, US Bank, Citibank, etc.

Comment: Dear Nick R, you seem to have done exactly what I am going to. So you say that HSBC was NOT willing to  open an account for you in Canada (remotely) while you  were still  in the UK?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Yes, that was my experience.  I tried to open my Canadian account while I was still in the UK but was told that this was not allowed and that I must present myself in person at a Canadian branch.  Since I was already an HSBC (Premier) account holder, there were no significant problems at the Canadian branch.  I simply sat down with an account manager, presented my passport and my UK account details to them, and the rest was immediate following my signature on a few forms.

Comment: Dear Nick R, so you did not need a Canadian address? Or you already had by then a rented apartment in Canada?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei I used a relative's address, since I briefly stayed with them when I first arrived.

Comment: Dear Nick R, and is there a reason for the address, does the bank send there something like documents or cards? Or can I just give them a temp address that I rent for a few weeks until they open my account? And then later when I am not living there anymore, and the bank sends there something and that gets returned, will the bank then close the account?